# Read registry value that contains spaces using batch file

Tags: batch-file, registry

I have a batch file that reads the registry value.

However the entry that I am reading contains spaces and I only seem to capture everything before the first space character when setting my variable.

```
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\My Entry"
set VALUE_NAME=Home

FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B
    set Home=%%C
)

if defined ValueName (
    @echo Home = %Home%
) else (
    @echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
)
```

The home registry entry actually contains this string: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dir1\Dir2" and the batch file only captures this: C:\Program

Does anybody have an idea of how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME%`?

Comment: The output is showing me the registry Name, Type and Data (Now in full i.e. includes the whole string :-)). How would I then store the data part of it in a variable? Thankss!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem happens because the string contains spaces and the second part of the string (possibly more parts if there are more spaces) are treated as another token (in 4, 5, etc.) To fix this, pass the rest of the line to %%C with an asterisk like this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B
    set Home=%%C
)
```

The asterisk (`*`) means to pass the rest of the line into the next variable (with all the spaces).

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. That was my worry as the path could actually have lots of spaces and therefore increasing tokens etc is impossible to determine? Thank you so much. I have changed my code and it seems to work a treat. Cheers

Comment: In my testing, `2*` causes variables to be created for each space separated element. So a `reg query` returning a path with spaces will produce a `%c` and `%d`. E.g.: `FOR /F "tokens=2,3* skip=2" %%L IN (
 'reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\WinSDKTools" /v InstallationFolder'
) DO echo %%M` returns `C:\Program` .

Answer (score 4):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\My Entry"
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Space Sciences Laboratory, U.C. Berkeley\BOINC Setup"
set VALUE_NAME=migrationdir

FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%A IN (
 `REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set "ValueName=%%A"
    set "ValueType=%%B"
    set Home="%%C"
)

IF DEFINED home SET home=%home:"=%
if defined Home echo Home = %Home%
if NOT defined Home echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
```

Since I don't have `...\My Entry` as a key, I've substituted a key I do have.

First item - since the data required contains a space, and space is a default delimiter, you need to use `1,2*` as tokens - the first, second and remainder-of-line.

The next little difficulty is that the data item ALSO contain `)` whic is interpreted as the closing parenthesis of the `FOR/f` hence giving an error - in your case, `\Dir1\Dir2` not expected here

A way to overcome this is to quote, then strip the value assigned to `home`

But once again, the closing-parenthesis in `home` serves to terminate the TRUE portion of the IF statement.

switching on the presence/absence of a value assigned to HOME overcomes this. Obviously, the same could be said for `Valuename` although there's a hidden fail-to-fail here.

If the requested registry entry is not found, then the `SET`s in the `FOR/f` are not performed, hence the values of the three variables are not changed from any value they may have before the `FOR/f` is executed. Therefore, if `home` (or `valuename` if you choose to use that value) has a value of `someexistingvalue` before the `for/f` then unexpected results may be presented.

(BTW - it's legitimate and neater-looking to break the `for/f` at either or both of the parentheses of the `IN` clause)

Comment: Wow what a great and in-depth answer! I am using the solution as described by user2033427 and it seems to work great. However you have given me some stuff to think about and good to have an explanation. The trick was adding the * to the tokens command. Thanks guys!

Comment: Hi, after playing around with both examples it seems that this one allowed me to check whether the home variable was assigned, the solution above was throwing an error as you pointed out when trying to check whether home was defined. Thanks I have used this code now as it seems to work great. So did the above apart from what I have just mentioned! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use `delims=:` for easy solution of unknown number of spaces in directory.
This solution should be use only for values of directory or file path with disc letter, so this is not universal solution...

```
ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

FOR /F "tokens=1,2* skip=2 delims=:" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "Administrative Tools" 2^>nul') DO (SET "regA=%%a" & SET "regB=%%b")
SET usrDeskPath=%regA:~-1%:%regB%

ECHO.
ECHO %usrDeskPath%
```